# Do I have to pay for a freelance contract?

Tags: freelance-websites

They offered me a freelance job to do data entry. only that to be able to be with the work they demand me the payment of 32usd. who tell me what the contract is for?
Is this so or is it a scam?
I am new to the freelance theme.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project owner is asking for refundable deposit](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/7571/project-owner-is-asking-for-refundable-deposit)

Answer (score 5):

**It's a scam.**

No *legitimate* client **EVER** needs money from you.

Worst case scenario is they would deduct any startup fees (which is really *exceptionally* rare, if they ever exist at all) from your first invoice.

**Never** pay any client even one penny to work for them. That's not how business works

Comment: thank you very much. you saved me I was about to pay for this job because I needed the payment .... but thanks ... I did not understand why I had to pay a contract ..... but you saved me ... thanks for helping me ... I will be eternally grateful for your time that you took to answer me and help me

Comment: No problem. Most of the time you can sort of stuff like this by merely thinking of how you do business yourself with others/contractors. If you hired someone to mow your lawn.. would *you* expect *them* to pay you anything for any reason???